# Another user edited his answer to include content from my answer, without giving me credit

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-answer, plagiarism

I am referring to the following post where the accepted answer was edited, or frankly re-written completely, roughly a year after posting my answer and by duplicating most of its content:
*[Modify Bash prompt prefix in OS X terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229576/modify-bash-prompt-prefix-in-osx-terminal?answertab=active#tab-top)*

[image]

The user did not bother giving me any credits for it and is likely to get upvotes for <s>his</s> my answer.

- Would you consider this behavior to be fair?
- Are Stack Overflow moderators allowing such practice?
- If the edit is cancelled for "deviating from original intent" or for duplicating answer, what happens to the upvotes received since the answer was duplicated?

Comment: The only thing copied, that I can see, is the list of flags for the tool. Which was infact copied from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html) (mostly) by both of you.

Comment: Well, you seem to have some reading issues. First of all I am quoting a book, so surely this is copied. If you look at the original answer, then the last edit, you should be able to see that both the flags and the prompt variables were copied.

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how the prompt variables were 'copied'. Merely explaining prompt variables and the fact that you *also* explained them, doesn't make it copying. In regards to copying; I was pointing out the fact that you appear to want credit for your answer for the parts they copied - however, those parts aren't original works in the first place, and it appears that they copied from the above link, and not your answer (regardless of whether or not your answer inspired them to do so).

Comment: The user just improved his answer, he does not *copy* yours. I have the feeling you are just jealous because you are no longer the only one to have provided a complete answer.

Comment: Although as expressed above (and I agree with them) that this answer was not copied from yours, just improved. In reference to _What happens to the upvotes received since the answer was duplicated_ They would just get removed from his total rep score, they wouldn't transfer to you (if that's what you were implying should/would happen) Moderators don't and **shouldn't** have the power to change peoples votes.

Answer (score 21):

First off, it strikes me as utterly disingenuous, that you are upset someone else failed to give you credit when **your entire answer is plagiarized from another source**. You do feebly note the title of the text you're going to copy from at the beginning of the post, but:

1. You don't give the author's name, which is a *fundamental* part of the citation. O'Reilly Press didn't generate that content, and it didn't come into being on its own. Someone had to take the time to write this, and by your own admission, deserves the credit for it. For online content, you also need to include a link to the original source. This isn't as necessary for books, but I like to include a link to the author's website or somewhere the book can be purchased if the reader finds the content useful. You have none of the above.
2. You failed to properly format content taken from another source as a *quotation*, thus giving at least the appearance that you might be trying to claim parts of it as your own. *Anything* you take directly from another source should be formatted as a block-level quotation to prevent misunderstandings about what is original and what is not.
3. You <strike>are likely to get upvotes</strike> have earned a *significant* amount of reputation from this answer, effectively giving *you* all the credit for *someone else's* work. It doesn't look like *anything* in your answer is original content, so you shouldn't be claiming or getting credit for it at all! (And again, I emphasize that this is a principle you obviously agree with, based on the wording of your question here.)

Wholesale copying like this from another source is not acceptable, even if you *were* taking proper care to cite and format it. Taking excerpts from another source is okay, with proper attribution, as is *summarizing* someone else's work. But copying the entire thing or even large portions of it puts you outside the realm of "fair use". As stated previously, you weren't *building* on others' work, using it as a reference for your own original content; you were just copying their materials.

In fact, even your edits in response to questions arising in the comments were copied-and-pasted from the same book, but that isn't clearly indicated in any way within the answer. Again, it looks like you're trying to claim these words as your own, saying that they are "answering BisTro['s] comment".

I also found another problem: you've posted this same content, with the same problems, in [another answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26357115/366904). You've also earned a large chunk of reputation from that answer. Except, that time, you didn't even bother to format it so that it is *readable* (code formatting for text? really?), much less as a quotation disclaiming your own authorship of it. **This whole answer is just a pathetic copy-paste job from the original source**, with no attempt even made to clean up its presentation. The citation is completely hidden at the bottom. Besides that, posting the same answer to multiple questions is frowned upon here; if you find two questions where the same exact answer can be posted, then you should be marking one of those questions as a duplicate.

On account of these concerns, I would delete both of those answers outright. I don't consider what you've done here to be fair or ethical, and Stack Overflow moderators do not allow plagiarism.

However, misbehavior on your part does not justify misbehavior on another user's part, so let's look at what you are accusing davidcondrey of doing. Looking at [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26232411), I don't see anything that is copied or plagiarized from your answer (which we've already established is *not* "your" answer) other than the syntax table. While I agree that he probably should have provided a source for that, since it *is* most likely that he pulled it from your answer<sup>*</sup>, the collation of a syntax table isn't exactly original work. All of the information it contains is readily available from multiple sources, and in fact, the *entire* syntax table appears in multiple sources online as well as in books, **including the Bash `man` page and [the official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html)**.

The rest of his answer is prose, syntax examples, and a variable list that he evidently composed/compiled independently. **Perhaps he was *inspired* by your answer (no one can say for sure), but there's nothing wrong with that!** We *want* users to improve their answers, and *continue* improving their answers. That davidcondrey did so does not mean that he did anything wrong—quite the contrary. He didn't *copy* your answer by any reasonable interpretation of the term, so nothing unethical or inappropriate happened here.

"Deviating from author's intent" is a potential reason to reject a third party's attempt to edit an answer, but attempting to apply this to an edit by the original author is nonsensical. He knows quite well what his intentions are.

__
<sub>* I say this because, as you point out, the revisions were made to his answer after your answer was posted, and it's hard to imagine that he didn't look elsewhere on the page after visiting it to update his answer. Then again, the presence of [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), like `â€™` in lieu of a quotation mark (originally present in his table but not in yours; I've since edited it out) suggests that he didn't simply copy-and-paste the table from your answer to his answer. It seems most likely he lifted it from an external source. So while I still agree that it requires a citation, there is less evidence than there might first appear that he copied it directly from you.</sub>

Comment: For the paragraph starting with, "Wholesale copying" you probably want to add something to indicate that such a quotation needs to be augmenting one's original content.  A post made *entirely* of quoted content, with no original content, even if the quotations are all excerpts, is typically considered plagiarism.

Comment: I don't know if my answer was unclear or just too long, but I didn't at all mean to imply that a link was sufficient. That item begins by saying that the author's name needs to be given, and the sentence that begins talking about a link includes the word "also". I know what a complete citation is. Do I really need to include an example? You can find this other places, and we aren't picky about the format, so I don't see the benefit in discussing this in any more detail. I also thought I conveyed the problem was *precisely* that the answer contained no original content. I even used that phrase.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, yes, I agree then that a link is not *necessary* for a book, but I do like to include it so that people who find the content useful can go and purchase it, which is the only way that the author is going to be compensated. I'll look at tweaking the wording there a bit.

Comment: Thank you. This answers perfectly.

Comment: @CodyGray Now that you're a moderator, has your opinion on this changed? Also, will you delete the two answers now?

Comment: I'm not sure why my opinion would have changed, @Magisch. Yes, the plagiarized answers should be deleted. I flagged them for moderator attention when I did the investigation brought about by this answer, but looking into it now, I see my flags have not been handled. I suppose I will handle them. Florian has had ample time to edit proper formatting and attribution into the answers by now, and he didn't. That's pretty telling.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the timely response. I saw the answers still up and was curious about the resolution for the situation.